# Applications on an account with Administrator privileges cannot run

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, file-permissions

Several applications cannot run in an Administrator account because they do not have permission to create files in the `%APPDATA%` folder.

Background:

- Running 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium Edition on a family computer.
- We have one normal account, `Family`, which has been running as administrator and without a password.
- I suffered a virus infection on the computer and made several changes, including a
  system restore, changing the account type of the normal family
  account to a standard user and assigning a password. The infection is
  solved, but I have been left in a state where several applications
  cannot run in the Family account because they do not have permission
  to create files in the `%APPDATA%` folder.

Symptoms include:

- Some applications (Chrome, Office) work properly with no problems.
- Some applications (eg Civilization III) give an `Access is Denied`
  error trying to create a file in `c:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Temp`.
  the same applies even when I choose to `Run as Administrator`
- Firefox gives a `Firefox is already running` error, which investigation
  suggests is really a permissions problem (Task Manager assures me it's definitely not already running).

Attempts to solve the problem:

- Changed the Family privileges back to administrator and removed the password. No luck.
- Ensured that the Family user has full control over the %APPDATA% folder.

Current state:

- Stuck. Frustrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a new account all together and trying that? If this works, I would recommend using this new account, and `ROBOCOPY`ing your user files over.

As well, if you were deleting files, maybe some system files got removed. Try clicking Start, typing `CMD` and press <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to launch as the Administrator. Type `SFC /scannow` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will have Windows scan for any system files that may have been affected. Pay attention to the output.

Comment: Thanks Luke. I tried the new account approach, although copying user files left me with some problems. In the end, I re-installed the major applications that were not functioning. The SFC command is not something I knew of before - thanks for that.

I suspect that as a result of my previous attempts I was seeing two separate problems (at least). Thunderbird, for example, was failing to start for one reason (presence of a parent.lock file) while an old game (Civ III) was failing because it is not permissions-aware enough for Windows 7. Thanks for the response.